# Storing numbers as (x, y) cordinates from a file at a specific point

Tags: c, arrays, file-io, c99

I have an [Instance File](http://pastebin.com/jt2etnwE) from which I need to store the **NUM_PT** and all the respective co-ordinates in the form of a 2D array system (***personal choice so I can access them easily***). I am able to retrieve the **NUM_PT** but I am stuck at reading the successive cordinates into my array.

**HERE IS WHAT I HAVE DONE**

```
/* Assignment 2 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <ctype.h>



#define MAXS 256

int main(int argc, char *argv[])

{

  int num_pt;
  int inputfile = 0, outputfile = 0, i;

  for (i = 1; i < argc; i++)
    {
      if (strcmp (argv[i], "-i") == 0)
          inputfile = i+1;
      if (strcmp (argv[i], "-o") == 0)
          outputfile = i+1;
    }
  if (inputfile == 0)
    {
      /* invalid command line options */
      printf("\nIncorrect command-line...\n");
      printf("> %s [-i inputfile [-o outputfile]]\n\n", argv[0]);
      exit(0);
    }

  FILE *fp;
  fp = fopen(argv[inputfile], "r");

  int count = 0;      
  if (fp == 0)
    {
      printf("\nCould not find %s\n", argv[inputfile]);
      exit(0);
    }

  char line[MAXS];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
      if (count == 4)
        {
         fscanf(fp, "%d", &num_pt);
         break;
        }
      else
        count++;

    }

  int arr[num_pt][1];
  while (fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
    {
      if (count == 5)
        {
          int k, j, cord;
          for (k = 0; k < num_pt; k++)
             {
              for (j = 0; j < num_pt; j++)
                 {
                   while (fscanf(fp, "%d%d", &cord) > 0)
                        {
                         arr[k][j] = cord;
                         j++;
                        }
                 }
              }
        }
    }
  fclose(fp)
  return 0;

}
```

After retrieving **NUM_PT** i tried reinitializing the `count` to 5 because the cordinates start from **LINE 6* in the file.

**ERROR FROM COMPILER**[image: ubuntu bash script]

**Language: c99 ; Compiler: gcc**

Comment: So you have a bunch of warnings and errors. What have you done to resolve them?

Comment: The warnings I am having trouble with are the first and second one. The third warning I haven't started on the portion where I need to implement output file. I have intialized the `arr[num_pt] [] ` and used it in my second for loop while scanning the coordinates but it tells me it's been unused.

Comment: So what the trouble is? Are you able to locate the line it is complaining about? Can you see anything wrong about it? How many numbers are you expecting to get there? How many variables are you passing to it?

Comment: @EugeneSh. If I was able to figure it all out I wouldn't have had asked the questionn. I am seeking help from the community.

Comment: The community here is to teach you something, not to solve all of you problems for you. I have asked you a bunch of questions above. If you start answering them on by one you will figure out that this specific problem is solved. So why won't you try?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sample for "Storing numbers as (x, y) cordinates from a file" (It is better not to fix the reading position)

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct point {
    int x, y;
} Point;

int readPoint(FILE *fp, Point *p);
int readInt(FILE *fp, int *n);

int main(void){
    FILE *fp = fopen("instance10_001.txt", "r");
    Point p;
    int MAX_X, MAX_Y;

    readPoint(fp, &p);
    MAX_X = p.x;
    MAX_Y = p.y;
    printf("MAX_X:%d, MAX_Y:%d\n", MAX_X, MAX_Y);

    int NUM_PT;
    readInt(fp, &NUM_PT);
    printf("NUM_PT:%d\n", NUM_PT);

    Point arr[NUM_PT];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_PT; ++i){
        readPoint(fp, &arr[i]);
        printf("Point(%d, %d)\n", arr[i].x, arr[i].y);
    }
    fclose(fp);
}

int readLine(FILE *fp, char *buff, int buff_size){
    while(fgets(buff, buff_size, fp)){
        if(*buff == '#' || *buff == '\n')
            continue;
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

#define LINE_MAX 128
int readPoint(FILE *fp, Point *p){
    char buff[LINE_MAX];
    if(readLine(fp, buff, sizeof buff)){
        return 2 == sscanf(buff, "%d %d", &p->x, &p->y);
    }
    return 0;
}
int readInt(FILE *fp, int *n){
    char buff[LINE_MAX];
    if(readLine(fp, buff, sizeof buff)){
        return 1 == sscanf(buff, "%d", n);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I have not learned the `struct` declaration in c. This helped me tons, I am planning on studying more about `struct` as I feel like it will be useful for my assignment. Thank you.

Comment: Case of use 2D array, `int arr[num_pt][1];` --> `int arr[num_pt][2];`

Comment: Are you saying I will be able to access my array type as `int arr[num_pt][1]` or is your method a substitute and a better way of approaching this question?

Comment: @ImtiazRaqib `int arr[num_pt][2];` then can access `arr[i][0]`(as x) and `arr[i][1]` (as y)  (i =0; i < num_pt; ++i)